# Yii Custom Validator creation

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii framework, so please any one help me for this question 
How to create custom validator class for the following validation,
I am having one table list , it is having listname and types on it, my validator want to check the list name to be unique for the specific type, for example,

```
listName Type
test1     1
test2     1
test3     2
```

when I insert a new list name validator, I want to retrieve the listnames and type and provide error if  it is not unique for the specific type.

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Have you tried CUniqueValidator? I lets you to set additional db criteria. You could set a condition for `type` field.

Comment: array('categoryName','ext.Validators.Validator','criteria'=>array('condition'=>'‌​appId=".$this->appId."')), i need query lik this "select * from tableName where appId='SomeValue'" I need to set the query lik this, but the pbm was $this->appId always returns Null value, so the error was not produced

Answer (score 1):

Well creating a custom validator method is really simple if that's what you are looking for.

1. You need a to add an element to rules() method in your Model (i.e protected/model/youTableName.php)

   `return array(
       array('listName', 'uniqueForType', 'type')
   );`
2. Create a method to youTableName.php named by the validator name.

   `public function uniqueForType($field, $params)
   {
       $filedToCompare = $this->$field;
       $fieldToCompareWith = $this->$params;
       // Do your checking and comparing
       if($weHaveAnError) {
           $this->addError($field, printf("This listName already exists for type %s", $this->$params));
       }
   }`

That should do the trick. Got that information form http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/20399-conditional-validation-rule/

Comment: Thanks, am did this in my model class already. But i want to reuse that code by seperate the class as validator class similarly as /framework/validators/CUniqueValidator class, please help me how to do this?  [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/) am referred this link but i cannot understood how to get the value, and how to pass the type column value into it.,

Comment: Oh ok, did little research and there was quite good documentation about this. It's nicely explained with samples. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/#hh1

Comment: DonRico, let me tell one scenerio please tell me how to handle that situation using custom validator class, when registering a new user we dont allow to get the username for the same email id again.

Comment: If I'm getting this correctly you don't allow to register with same e-mail more than once. That's is really simple and common rule. You just need to add a 'unique' validator for e-mail field and that's all.

Comment: `public function rules() {array('email', 'unique')}`

That should be all you need. You should consider making email field in db table unique field as well.

Comment: Sorry that is not my problem. am told that scenario for your underastanding purpose.,please see the above question regarding to that i need solution and advance thanks for that.,

Comment: array('categoryName','ext.Validators.Validator','criteria'=>array('condition'=>'appId=".$this->appId."')), i need query lik this "select * from tableName where appId='SomeValue'"  I need to set the query lik this, but the pbm was $this->appId always returns Null value, so the error was not produced